# Loop over a list in NixOS using the value as an identifier?

Tags: nix, nixos

In vhost.nix I want to add the users in a loop like the working example in httpd.virtualHosts.

This is the `configuration.nix` I am using in a virtual machine:

```
# vm.nix
{ lib, config, ... }:
{
  imports = [
    ./vhosts.nix
  ];

  services.httpd.enable = true;

  vhosts = {
    "test.example.de" = {
      customer = "web2";
      phpuser = "web2www1";
    };
    "test2.example.de" = {
      customer = "web3";
      phpuser = "web3www1";
    };
  };

}
```

this my module `vhost.nix`

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }: 
with lib;
let
  cfg = config.vhosts;
in
  {
    options.vhosts = lib.mkOption {
      type = with lib.types; attrsOf (submodule ({domain, ... }: {
        options = {
          customer = mkOption {
            type = str;
          };
          phpuser = mkOption {
            type = str;
          };
        };
      }));
    };
    config = {
      services.httpd.virtualHosts = lib.mapAttrs (domain: cfg: {
        documentRoot = "/srv/www/${cfg.customer}/${domain}";
      }) cfg;

      # how do I solve this in a loop like above ?
      users.users.web2www1.isNormalUser = true;  
      users.users.web3www1.isNormalUser = true;
    };
  }
```

how do I solve this in a loop like above ?

Comment: Nix doesn't have for loops as far as I know, instead one would use map instead: https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/builtins.html#builtins-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569447/loop-over-a-list-in-nixos-using-the-value-as-an-identifier#comment136752900_77569447) by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663462/chris-stryczynski), in Nix, traditional imperative programming constructs like for-loops are not used. Instead, functional programming paradigms are employed, specifically functions like `map`, `fold`, and `filter` that operate on lists or attribute sets.

You can use [`mapAttrs f attrset`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/builtins.html#builtins-mapAttrs):

```hs
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }: 
with lib;
let
  cfg = config.vhosts;
in
  {
    options.vhosts = lib.mkOption {
      type = with lib.types; attrsOf (submodule ({domain, ... }: {
        options = {
          customer = mkOption {
            type = str;
          };
          phpuser = mkOption {
            type = str;
          };
        };
      }));
    };
    config = {
      services.httpd.virtualHosts = lib.mapAttrs (domain: cfg: {
        documentRoot = "/srv/www/${cfg.customer}/${domain}";
      }) cfg;

      users.users = lib.foldl' (acc: domain: let
                                  user = cfg.${domain}.phpuser;
                                in acc // { "${user}".isNormalUser = true; }
                                ) {} (lib.attrNames cfg);
    };
  }
```

`lib.foldl'` is used to iterate over the `vhosts` attribute set.
For each domain in `vhosts`, it extracts the `phpuser` and sets `isNormalUser` to `true` in the user's configuration.